# Auto select Radio Button in Play Framework Template

Tags: html, playframework, radio-button

I am trying to auto populate the radio button in the View. The value is actually saved in the database.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="radio" id="${field.id}" name="${field.name}" class="${field.errorClass}" value="1" />Yes
<input type="radio" id="${field.id}" name="${field.name}" class="${field.errorClass}" value="0" />No
```

But Play Framework does not auto select the radio button when I edit the record. 
How can I know why?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you filling your form object and passing it back to the view when you retrieve the data from the database? Please post your controller code which retrieves the data and passes it to your view

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" id="${field.id}" name="${field.name}" class="${field.errorClass}" value="1" />Yes
```

Use the checked attribute in your code on the radio button you want to be selected at the start.

i.e

```
<input type="radio" id="${field.id}" name="${field.name}" class="${field.errorClass}" value="1" checked />Yes
```

Comment: No. I am trying to auto populate from the database. Not hardcoding a default value.